# Numpy "ma.where" has different behaviour from "where"... How can I make it behave the same?

Tags: arrays, numpy, broadcast

So I'm trying to use the `numpy.ma.where` to create an array for me, in the same way as the `numpy.where` function can. The `where` function broadcasts my column array then replaces some of the elements with zeros. I get the following:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> condition = numpy.array([True,False, True, True, False, True]).reshape((3,2))
>>> print (condition)
[[ True False]
 [ True  True]
 [False  True]]
>>> broadcast_column = numpy.array([1,2,3]).reshape((-1,1)) # Column to be broadcast
>>> print (broadcast_column)
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]]
>>> numpy.where(condition, broadcast_column, 0) \
... # Yields the expected output, column is broadcast then condition applied
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 2],
       [0, 3]])
>>> numpy.ma.where(condition, broadcast_column, 0).data \
... # using the ma.where function yields a *different* array! Why?
array([[1, 0],
       [3, 1],
       [0, 3]], dtype=int32)
>>> numpy.ma.where(condition, broadcast_column.repeat(2,axis=1), 0).data \
... # The problem doesn't occur if broadcasting isnt used
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 2],
       [0, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

Many thanks for your help!

My numpy version is 1.6.2

Answer (score 2):

At the heart of `np.ma.where` is the statement:
(On Ubuntu, see /usr/share/pyshared/numpy/ma/core.py)

```
np.putmask(_data, fc, xv.astype(ndtype))
```

`_data` is the data in the masked array to be returned.

`fc` is boolean array which is True where the condition is True.

`xv.astype(ndtype)` is the value to be inserted, e.g. `broadcast_column`.

```
In [90]: d = np.empty(fc.shape, dtype=ndtype).view(np.ma.MaskedArray)

In [91]: _data = d._data

In [92]: _data
Out[92]: 
array([[5772360, 5772360],
       [      0,      17],
       [5772344, 5772344]])

In [93]: fc
Out[93]: 
array([[ True, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [94]: xv.astype(ndtype)
Out[94]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

In [95]: np.putmask(_data, fc, xv.astype(ndtype))

In [96]: _data
Out[96]: 
array([[      1, 5772360],
       [      3,       1],
       [5772344,       3]])
```

Notice the 3 and the 1 in the middle row of the array.

**The problem is that `np.putmask` does not broadcast values, it repeats them:**

From the docstring for `np.putmask`:

> putmask(a, mask, values)
>
> Sets `a.flat[n] = values[n]` for each n where `mask.flat[n]==True`.
>
> If `values` is not the same size as `a` and `mask` then it will
>   repeat. This gives behavior different from `a[mask] = values`.

When you explicitly broadcast, `flat` returns the desired flattened values:

```
In [97]: list(broadcast_column.repeat(2,axis=1).flat)
Out[97]: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

But if you do not broadcast,

```
In [99]: list(broadcast_column.flat) + list(broadcast_column.flat)
Out[99]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

the correct values are not in the desired positions.

---

PS. In the latest version of numpy, [the code reads](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/ma/core.py#L6568)

```
np.copyto(_data, xv.astype(ndtype), where=fc)
```

I'm not sure what effect this has on the behavior; I don't have a new enough verison of numpy to test.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the new version of numpy this works as expected becuase copyto does broadcast, sorry...

Comment: @seberg: Thanks for checking this out.